# depth of field is not rendering but does show in preview

Tags: animation

[image: Node Setup]I am using blender 2.79 and the depth of field works in preview just fine but when I render it doesn't show the blur.
I've checked most the setting I know about for depth of field.
Shading is set to depth of field
the f-stop is set at 0.5
Object is selected (a Barrel).
I am using Blender Render Not Cycle Render.
I have tried using nodes and i get the same results.

Comment: Show us an image of your node setup, please.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/depth-of-field-f-stop-not-doing-anything/36182#36182